# How to copy cell values from multiple (but not all) rows and columns from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I developed an Excel tool that - after (de)selecting several options - shows the user/employee the correct price to sell the product for to the customer.

The worksheet the user uses (i.e., "Particulier") retrieves data from several other sheets; one of these sheets is a price list (i.e. "Toestelprijzen Start") that needs to be updated every once in a while: Every week I receive a new price list with new product prices which I use to update the old prices in the Excel tool. To do so, I use the following code that works perfectly fine:

```
Sub ImportPrijslijstStart()
    Dim sImportFile As String, sFile As String
    Dim sThisBk As Workbook
    Dim vfilename As Variant
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set sThisBk = ActiveWorkbook
    sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook")
    If sImportFile = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No File Selected!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        vfilename = Split(sImportFile, "\")
        sFile = vfilename(UBound(vfilename))
        Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sImportFile

        Set wbBk = Workbooks(sFile)
        With wbBk
            If SheetExists("VF Start incl. BTW") Then
                Set wsSht = .Sheets("VF Start incl. BTW")
                wsSht.Copy before:=sThisBk.Sheets("Toestelprijzen Start")
            Else
                MsgBox "Er is geen sheet met de naam VF Start incl. BTW in:"&vbCr& .Name
            End If
            wbBk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Prijslijst geïmporteerd"
End Sub

Private Function SheetExists(sWSName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(sWSName)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

Each product (350 items) on this new imported price list has different prices depending on which options are selected on the "Particulier" worksheet. That is, each product on this price list has 31 different prices.

The first 2 columns (A & B) display product number, the 3rd column (C) displays the product name, and column D:AH display the product prices. Next, headings are on row 1-6 and product prices start on row 7. Thus, this new imported sheet has data in cells A1:AH357, where cells D7:AH357 display product prices.

However, sometimes new products are added, and older ones are deleted from the new price list, which means row 357 is not always the last row. Next, I want to copy (i.e., "update") the prices from this new imported worksheet to the worksheet with the old prices.

I copy the prices from the new to the old worksheet, because on this new price list products that come in different colors are displayed several times. Each color is displayed as a unique product with a unique product number, but with the same price for each color.

However, I only need prices from each product once (e.g., Product X comes in black, white, gold, and pink, but Product X its price is the same regardless its color, so I only need to copy the 31 prices in columns D:AH from 1 of these 4 colors). To do so, I use `VLOOKUP` to search for the unique product number used in both the old price list and in the new price list.

However, my code does not work the way I want it to. It only copies one column, rather than the 31 columns D:AH. Also, it copies all info twice; that is, it successfully searches for and finds (copies) the values (prices) in the first column (D) from the new imported price list to the sheet with the old prices (to update the prices) from, say, row 7 to row 87 (only 80 rows because there are 80 items with unique product numbers), but, subsequently, it pastes all data (prices) a second time on row 88 to row 168.

Furthermore, when running the code it takes about 40 seconds to finish. I have absolutely no clue why my code:

- copies data from only one column and not 31 columns
- pastes the data twice
- takes so long to finish

I am looking for help to solve these three issues.

Please find below the code that I use:

```
Sub PrijslijstUpdatenStart()
    Dim Osh As Worksheet
    'Sheet with the new product prices:
    Set Osh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VF Start incl. BTW") 
    Dim Orange As String
    Dim Olength As Integer
    Olength = Osh.Range("B1", Osh.Range("B7").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Orange = "B7:AH" & Olength    
    Dim Nsh As Worksheet
    'Sheet on which the old prices are displayed that need to be updated with the 
    '   new prices on "VF Start incl. BTW":
    Set Nsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Toestelprijzen Start") 
    Dim Nrange As String
    Dim Nlength As Integer
    Nlength = Nsh.Range("B1", Nsh.Range("B10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Nrange = "B10:AG" & Nlength
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Dept_Row As Long
    Dim Dept_Clm As Long
    Table1 = Nsh.Range(Nrange)
    Table2 = Osh.Range(Orange)
    Dept_Row = Nsh.Range("E10:AH" & Olength).Row
    Dept_Clm = Nsh.Range("E10:AH" & Olength).Column
    For Each cl In Table1
        Nsh.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = _
                  Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
        Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
    Next cl
End Sub
```

I tried to describe the situation as clear as possible. If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: As far as I can see, in `PrijslijstUpdatenStart` the lines `Dept_Row = Nsh.Range("E10:AH" & Olength).Row` and `Dept_Clm = Nsh.Range("E10:AH" & Olength).Column` will be setting `Dept_Row` to 10 and `Dept_Clm` to 5, so your loop through every cell in "B10:AGx" will be only updating the one cell E10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I use a Dictionary to store the product names as keys and new values as arrays from the first worksheet.  I then iterate over the second worksheet and when a match is found, assign the value array to the adjacent columns.

```
Sub PrijslijstUpdatenStart()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VF Start incl. BTW")
        For Each r In .Range("B7", .Range("B7").End(xlDown))
            If Not dict.Exists(r.Value) Then dict.Add r.Value, r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 31).Value
        Next
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Toestelprijzen Start")
        For Each r In .Range("B10", .Range("B10").End(xlDown))
            If dict.Exists(r.Value) Then r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 31).Value = dict(r.Value)
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Update:** Delete the old products that are missing from the new price list.

---

```
Sub PrijslijstUpdatenStart()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VF Start incl. BTW")
        For Each r In .Range("B7", .Range("B7").End(xlDown))
            If Not dict.Exists(r.Value) Then dict.Add r.Value, r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 31).Value
        Next
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Toestelprijzen Start")
        For x = .Range("B10").End(xlDown).Row To 10 Step -1
            If dict.Exists(.Cells(x, "B").Value) Then
                .Cells(x, "C").Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 31).Value = dict(.Cells(x, "C").Value)
            Else
                .Rows(x).Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, it gives an 1004 error on the `For Each r In Range("B7", Osh.Range("B7").End(xlDown))` line. I cannot figure out why it return this 1004 error.

Comment: This works perfectly fine! Thank you so much! Can I ask you one more thing? Sometimes products that are in my price list are no longer in the new price list. Is there a possibility to check whether or not all product numbers in my price list are still in the new price list, and if not, that product will be deleted automatically? Thanks again!

Comment: See my updated answer. You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=42)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it! The current code returns a 424 error on this line: `.Cells(x, "C").Resize(1, 31).Value = dict(r.Value)`

Comment: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/f024cc7f97acd86450c283463b1e2b9e20161104172301/2f7e07c02da25bfa07ee3a56c738d54c20161104172301/eff6ba here you go. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you so much, this works exactly as I want it to! The only thing I added is `Offset(0, 1)` in this line: .Cells(x, "C").Resize(1, 31).Value = dict(.Cells(x, "C").Value)`, which thus now has become `.Cells(x, "C").Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 31).Value = dict(.Cells(x, "C").Value)`. Include `Offset` was not necessary per se for this particular example, but in my document I needed `Offset` to be `Offset(0, 2)`, therefore I added it in your code. Maybe you can edit your code to include this.